# Why onProgressUpdate() doesn't get called on Gingerbread when working in standalone service?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

A bit convoluted situation -

- A Service is packaged as a separate APK with nothing other than it in the manifest;
- The Service accepts incoming requests and handles them with MessageHandler;
- In one case, a handler spawns an AsyncTask like this:

  ```
  private class XHandler implements MessageHandler {

      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message incoming) {

          Bundle b = incoming.getData();

          ...            
          new XAsyncTask(...).execute();
      }
  }
  ```
- A textbook simple async task reports progress
- ... in ICS, but not in Gingerbread.

What is it - a bug?

AsyncTask documentation says "onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...)." However, there's no such thing as UI thread for standalone services, is there?

Documentation on services says "A service runs in the main thread of the application that hosts it, b default" - does this constitute UI thread?

**UPDATE 2012/07/10:** Changing android:targetSdkVersion="10" to android:targetSdkVersion="15" causes the same effect when the app is run on ICS. The only working combination so far is targetSdkVersion="10" running on API 15.

Comment: why you ccombine Handler and AsyncTask?

Comment: @hawaii: There may be several tasks spawned per one handler call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question about main/ui thread is explained fairly well on this page: [Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

> When an application is launched, the system creates a thread of execution for the application, called "main." This thread is very important because it is in charge of dispatching events to the appropriate user interface widgets, including drawing events. It is also the thread in which your application interacts with components from the Android UI toolkit (components from the android.widget and android.view packages). As such, the main thread is also sometimes called the UI thread.

Not sure how to help you with your AsyncTask. What are you trying to do? How is your Service implemented? What is it you want to do when the AsyncTask is done?

Why are you not using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)?

Comment: IntentService is way too simple for the task - here, hardware and Internet communications are happening in background. Implementation details are unimportant - but here's this fact: it all works on ICS, and with the service packaged within the same APK - regardless of whether it works in the default application process or its own.

Comment: I created two apks, one with a service that shows a toast in onProgressUpdate of a asynctask and one with an activity that starts the service. I tried it on an Android 2.3.3 (api level 10) avd instance and it worked just fine. Is something more needed to reproduce your problem?

Comment: this one is more complicated - it makes an IPC call in onProgressUpdate. Upon further consideration, I decided to drop AsyncTask and just implement it as a thread.